# VHDL error "indexed name returns a value whose type does not match "std_logic_vector", the type of the target expression"

Tags: vhdl, run-length-encoding

I can't find out what's going wrong in this snippet of my code.

The error occurs on the `data_in_bit <=data_in(posit + 1)`

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;

entity rle004 is
port(
data_in : in std_logic_vector(39 downto 0);
clk     : in std_logic;
rst_n   : in std_logic;
sync    : in std_logic;
data_out: out std_logic_vector(39 downto 0);
valid   : out std_logic
);
end entity;

architecture gedrag of rle004 is
    signal data_in_bit: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal equal :boolean := false; 
 begin  

input:process(data_in, clk, rst_n) is

    variable posit:     integer:= 0;

begin
    if rst_n = '1' then
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            data_in_bit <= data_in(posit + 1);
        end if;
        
        if posit < '0' then
            posit := '0';
        end if;
        
        if data_in_bit = data_in(posit-1) then
            equal <= true;
        end if;
    elsif rst_n = '1' then
        data_in_bit <= 'X';
    end if;
    
end process input;
end architecture gedrag;
```

This code occurs one after the other, there isn't anything between this.

Comment: There are additional errors in your code. At least 5 total, all showing a lack of understanding of VHDL's type system and semantics. For `data_in_bit <= data_in(posit + 1);` The assignment target `data_in_bit` is type std_logic_vector, an array type while the indexed name `data_in(posit + 1) of the right hand wafeform expression` is of the element type of std_logic_vector and is a scalar, enumerated type.

Comment: The [5 apparent errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5WCA.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

`data_in(posit-1)` returns a single `std_logic`. but `data_in_bit` is an array of length 8. You cannot compare an 8 bit array to a single bit.